# Laravel Eloquent Relationship with User and Agent

Tags: laravel, model, migration, eloquent-relationship

Please, guys, I need your help.

I want to implement a system where a user can be an agent (with a name they desire to call their agency). Also, when it is approved by the admin, many users can belong to this agency during their sign-up process by referencing the agent ID.

Here's what I have tried...

In User.php

```
public function agent(){
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::class, 'agent_id', 'id');
}
```

In Agent.php

```
public function users(){
   return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'agent_id', 'id');
}
```

And then in the migrations: I have the **'agent_id'** in the users migration and **'user_id'** in the agent migration.

Is there something I'm missing?

How do I set up the relationship, both Model and migration properly?

It seems I'm misunderstanding things now...

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have a User model? If that's the case, can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68130410/edit) it to the question?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Seems like you've already set up the relationship and only the migration/database table is missing, right?

Comment: Yes. I've already written how the migrations for both tables are structured. If you read my question again maybe you'll get what I meant

Comment: What is your problem with the migration. Do you already have any migration code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the second and third argument in User.php:

```php
public function agent(){
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::class, 'id', 'agent_id');
}
```

Comment: Ok will try this. Thanks